# Access Spring ApplicationContext from TilesPreparer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

In my application I have the class

```
public class SomeTilesPreparer implements ViewPreparer { ..
  @Autowired Bean bean;
```

That is used to dynamically setup tiles.

This class is only implemented in tiles.xml,

```
<definition name=".v1" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/v1/template.jsp" preparer="package.SomeTilesPreparer">
    <put-attribute name="title"       value="Some Titles" />
    ...
</definition>
```

I do not how it is created. I need to access the context from that class.  No matter how I autowire the bean, it is null. I tried implementing ApplicationContextAware but it did not work.

I also have this class in applicationContext.xml.

How do I access a bean from the context from that class ?

Answer (score 0):

If your bean is null that means that your `SomeTilesPreparer` class is not managed by Spring. If iw was then you'd get an exception if Spring was not able to autowire a field.

How do you create it? You either need to create it in your java/xml configuration or annotate it with one of the `@Component` annotation and make sure package scanning includes package for the class in question. Once you made Spring to create an instance of class for you, the rest of the stuff should work.

This is all regardless of what the class does, just basic Spring.

Comment: I am not sure how this class is created, the only places you can find the class is tiles.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things slightly clear... Dependency Injection works only in Spring Components. Which means that `SomeTilesPreparer` needs to be a Spring component to successfully autowire the component `Bean`.

Implementing `ApplicationContextAware` enables you Spring component to access `applicationContext`.

So basically what you are trying to do will not work simply.

**EDIT**

If you still insist to use it this way, I propose something like this:

```
public class ApplicationContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext ctx;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException      {
    ctx = appContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    if (ctx == null) {
        logger.info(CloudServicesLogUtil
            .getLogMessage("Could not get Application Context from Web Application. Creating Application Context"));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext localCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        localCtx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("production");
        localCtx.scan("packages to scan");
        localCtx.refresh();
        ctx = localCtx;
    }
    return ctx;
}
}
```

Now make this bean a Spring component either using XML config or Java config. Below is a Java configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "applicationContextUtil")
public ApplicationContextUtil getApplicationContextUtil() {
    return new ApplicationContextUtil();
}
```

With all this in place you can always invoke `ApplicationContextUtil.getApplicationContext()` and you can get a the `Bean` instance which is a Spring component.

Comment: I have no idea how this class is created, and that is the problem.

Comment: Please check my EDIT. I gave you a working solution, which I use to get a Spring Bean in a non Spring project.

Comment: that gives the exception. SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Comment: when you say "If you still insist to use it this way" what is the recommended way ?

Comment: Well, the ideal scenario is to have all the components Spring managed. But clearly your scenario is different. So you can check this blog post : http://java.dzone.com/articles/injecting-spring-beans-non